# How do I space out the contents of my <ul>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to space out the contents to be evenly and then spaces to all have equal amount but I'm not sure how to do so. When I add padding to the list or increase the space in the column it messes up the format of the page

I have also tride putting an offset in the row but it still doesnt fix it
So I'm trying for it to be like:

```
      Projects          About Me          Contact Me
      Pic               Pic               Pic
```

But anytime I change something it changes to:

```
      Projects Pic         About Me          Contact Me
                           Pic               Pic
```

```css
.header {
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, darkgray, lightblue);
}

.home {
  width: 100%;
}

.home div {
  width: 200px;
}

.home img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.home ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.home li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.home a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: steelblue;
}

.home a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkblue;
}

.home img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:mintcream">
  <div class="header">
    <span style="color:darkblue">const</span>
    <span style="color:white">_name =</span>
    <span style="color:darkblue">"My_Name"</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="home" style="padding-top:20px;">
      <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <span style="font-size:35px">Projects</span>
          <span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff"/
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <span style="font-size:35px">About Me</span>
          <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" /></div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-2">
        <a href="#">
          <span style="font-size:35px">Contact Me</span>
          <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" /></div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please check it is reflecting your question. For example use a picture from placeholder.com

Comment: Yes, it is reflecting my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @apanesar11 pointed out, grids should resolve your problem.
Another solution is the use of the flexbox.
I made you and example with the snippet given by @mplungjan :
https://codepen.io/mdubus/pen/BvXXmJ

```
.home {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

If you're not satisfied with the alignment, you can also replace the `justify-content:space-around;` in .home with `justify-content:space-between;`. 
I'm not sure about the kind of alignment you want, but hope it helps ! :)

EDIT : 
I also changed the .home a with

`display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;` so that your picture goes under your text.

Comment: Why not leave the snippet here? You could just "Copy to answer"

Comment: You're right. I'm new here and didn't saw that button. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

have you used grid systems? It'll make everything a lot easier to do and your webpage much more responsive. Check out some of my sample code here: https://github.com/apanesar11/CSS-Grids

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having this behavior currently is because span is an *inline* element, whereas div is a *block* element. Because of this the about.png and phone.jpg images are positioned currently, because start a new, since they are wrapped in a div element. Your project.jpg img is wrapped within a span element and span elements do not start on a new line and they take only the space they need.